# Use scala in spark to save prediction result into HDFS table is VERY slow on yarn-cluster mode

Tags: performance, scala, apache-spark, machine-learning, hdfs

I used scala to build a machine learning project in spark and use spark-submit to launch it with "--master yarn-cluster" as the parameter. The computing steps are very fast, but it always gets stuck at the writing tables step for hours. The output is just 3Mb. Has anyone had this problem before?

the scala writing table code is listed as below

```
mlPredictResult
  .select("orderid","prediction")
  .write
  .mode(SaveMode.Overwrite)
  .saveAsTable("tmp_sbu_vadmtestdb.AntiCF_ClickFarming_predicted")
```

the spark-submit code is listed as below

```
spark-submit  --class Ml_Learning --master yarn-cluster --executor-memory 5G --num-executors 50 AntiCF-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar
```

Comment: This might be better suited on code review as the code does work even though it's performance needs to be increased

Comment: what is allocated resources for driver ?

Answer (score 1):

In Spark, there are two types of commands, transformations (which are "lazy" i.e. they will be executed only when needed) and actions (which are executed immediately).

I assume that:
- The computing steps seems to be very fast as they are lazy.
- The write/saveAsTable seems to be very slow, as it is an action which trigger spark to perform the lazy transformation which weren't calculated till this point.

==> the reason it takes a lot of time to write to disk, is caused due to the need to perform the calculation before writing to the disk.

http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/programming-guide.html

*RDDs support two types of operations: transformations, which create a new dataset from an existing one, and actions, which return a value to the driver program after running a computation on the dataset. For example, map is a transformation that passes each dataset element through a function and returns a new RDD representing the results. On the other hand, reduce is an action that aggregates all the elements of the RDD using some function and returns the final result to the driver program (although there is also a parallel reduceByKey that returns a distributed dataset).
**All transformations in Spark are lazy, in that they do not compute their results right away**. Instead, they just remember the transformations applied to some base dataset (e.g. a file). **The transformations are only computed when an action requires a result to be returned to the driver program**. This design enables Spark to run more efficiently. For example, we can realize that a dataset created through map will be used in a reduce and return only the result of the reduce to the driver, rather than the larger mapped dataset.
*

**Note: It is possible that modifying your machine learning spark code and/or spark resources will reduce the calculation time**